# How can disable navbar in Flask-Admin?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

I want Disable navbar in Flask-Admin.
I want to access directly to operation with /admin/something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in the Flask-Admin Github repository of customizing the layout, [Custom Layout](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/custom-layout).

In your particular case you need to remove the `<nav></nav>` html section within the `{% block page_body %}` Jinja2 block of the [base layout](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/base.html) template file.

Create a file `menuless-layout.html` in your project's `templates/admin` directory which  extends the built-in base layout. Copy and paste the `{% block page_body %}{% endblock %}` block and delete the `<nav></nav>` section.

```
{% import 'admin/layout.html' as layout with context -%}
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% block page_body %}
  <div class="container{%if config.get('FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT', False) %}-fluid{% endif %}">

    <!-- Nav section removed -->

    {% block messages %}
    {{ layout.messages() }}
    {% endblock %}

    {# store the jinja2 context for form_rules rendering logic #}
    {% set render_ctx = h.resolve_ctx() %}

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then instruct Flask-Admin to use this template as the base layout:

```
# Create admin with custom base template
admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example', base_template='admin/menuless-layout.html', template_mode='bootstrap3')
```